# Number of sub-arrays with element included

Tags: combinations

Suppose we have an array of numbers `{x1, x2, x3 ...... xn}`. If we select an element `Xi` from this array, how many sub-arrays exist with this element included?

Comment: Contiguous. I think sub-array implies that. Non-contiguous would probably be a subsequence

Comment: Don't use $\{ \ldots \}$ for (finite or infinite) sequences. Use $( \ldots )$ instead. Also, [use MathJax to format your posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any contiguous subarray looks like $(x_a,x_{a+1},\ldots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1}\ldots,x_{b-1},x_b)$ where $a\leq i\leq b$.
That gives you $i$ ways to choose $a$ and $n-i+1$ ways to choose $b$.
Take the product to get $i(n-i+1)$ subarrays.

Comment: Is ```n``` the length of the whole array?

Comment: Yes, that's how you used it.